# How to map entity descendant to a view?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity model class `DirectoryUser`. and corresponding SQL Server table.
I've created a view which adds one additional varchar column named Roles to the table which `DirectoryUser` is mapped. (the column uses STRING_AGG to concatenate Role names in which the user belongs)

Now I would like to map this view as (keyless?) `DbSet` mapped to the model type `DirectoryUserWithRoles`. It sounds reasonable I do not copy and paste all properties from `DirectoryUser` to  `DirectoryUserWithRoles` instead did this:

```
public class DirectoryUserWithRoles : DirectoryUser
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and added this line to my context

```
public DbSet<DirectoryUserWithRoles> DirectoryUsersWithRoles { get; set; }
```

and in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DirectoryUserWithRoles>(eb =>
{
    //eb.HasNoKey();
    eb.ToView("UsersWithRoles");
});
```

I ***do*** understand that I am confusing EF because `DirectoryUserWithRoles` ***is a*** `DirectoryUser` and the sophisticated inheritance O/R mapping logic interprets the model based on that 'is a' relation.

So when trying to PM>add-migration in PM is got the exception saying:

> The entity type 'DirectoryUserWithRoles' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'DirectoryUser'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table.

Adding (uncommenting) `eb.HasNoKey();` does not help:

> A 'DirectoryUserWithRoles' cannot be configured as keyless because it is a derived type. The root type 'DirectoryUser' must be configured as keyless.

**Question**

If I would like to have an entity model class and a DbSet mapped to my view, is my only chance to duplicate (copy and paste) `DirectoryUser` class as `DirectoryUserWithRoles`?

Comment: Create an abstract class `DirectoryUserBase` of which both classes inherit while EF doesn't know the base class.

Comment: @GertArnold, thx but unfortunately `DirectoryUser`  must inherit the built in `IdentityUser`... :-(

Comment: So `DirectoryUserBase` could as well. `DirectoryUser` will still "be a" `IdentityUser`.